# spring boot hystrix integration

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

I have the following method

```
@HystrixCommand(commandKey="operator",fallbackMethod="getFakeResponse",commandProperties = {
        @HystrixProperty(name = "hystrix.command.operator.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "30000")
})
public String getResponse(){

    try {
        Thread.sleep(6000000l);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //  e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return "the real thing";
}
```

when ever I try to run my unit test code to test it, I get the following exception

> com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.exception.HystrixPropertyException: Failed to set Command properties. groupKey: 'HystrixComponentPOC', commandKey: 'operator', threadPoolKey: ''
>       at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericSetterBuilder.build(GenericSetterBuilder.java:88)
>       at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.AbstractHystrixCommand.(AbstractHystrixCommand.java:52)
>       at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericCommand.(GenericCommand.java:35)
>       at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.HystrixCommandFactory.create(HystrixCommandFactory.java:44)
>       at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.aop.aspectj.HystrixCommandAspect.methodsAnnotatedWithHystrixCommand(HystrixCommandAspect.java:85)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
>       at com.masary.topup.HystrixComponentPOC$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$95f9b3dd.getResponse()
>       at com.masary.topup.refactor.LedgerUpdateTestCases.test(LedgerUpdateTestCases.java:50)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown command property: hystrix.command.operator.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds
>       at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.conf.HystrixPropertiesManager.initializeProperties(HystrixPropertiesManager.java:125)
>       at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.conf.HystrixPropertiesManager.initializeCommandProperties(HystrixPropertiesManager.java:99)
>       at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericSetterBuilder.build(GenericSetterBuilder.java:86)
>       ... 47 more

however, I can run it successfully with the excepted behavior when i remove annotation and add

> hystrix.command.operator.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=30000

to my properties file

by the way the only configuration I have is @EnableHystrix on my main class and I am using spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE

any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this is the correct command property name?
Shouldn't it be

`@HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "30000")`

instead?

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds

also some snippet from one of their tests that may be helpful
https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/d838f4d1ba65ce55755ab1c73f74c980f04572bf/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica/src/test/java/com/netflix/hystrix/contrib/javanica/test/common/configuration/command/BasicCommandPropertiesTest.java#L155